# selenium webdriver chrome 116 stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, driver

I had webdriver-manager 4.0.0 and Selenium 4.8.0 installed. I was using the below which worked fine.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()), options=Options())
```

My organisation upgraded to Chrome 16 and now the above no longer works. I understand that with selenium 4.11.2 webdriver manager is no longer required, as selenium manager automatically handles the driver and browser itself. So I upgraded to selenium 4.11.2.

I tried this:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

And this:

```
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Both are solutions I found online which resolved the issue for most people but not for me.

I will post parts of the error log in the console below:

```
E           selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: G:\some_path\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\window
s\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.
E           {'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error tr
ying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection faile
d because connected host has failed to respond. (os error 10060)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}
 
 
E           selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

Can anyone assist me with this please? Is the issue something to do with my organisations security/proxy settings or am I overlooking something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you manually copy the following end-point on your browser and hit enter? See if you get response. `https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json`

Comment: Hi Shawn. When I copy and paste the URL into chrome browser I am directed to a page full of code i.e. `{"timestamp":"2023-08-21T11:08:04.604Z","versions":[{"version":"113.0.5672.0","revision":"1121455","downloads":{"chrome":[{"platform":"linux64","url":"https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/113.0.5672.0/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip"},{"platform":"mac-arm64","url":"https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/113.0.5672.0/mac-arm64/chrome-mac-arm64.zip"},{"platform":"mac-x64","url":"https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/113.0.5672.0/m`

Comment: Hope you tried that on the same machine where you are running your code? My guess is that your organisation network is not allowing `selenium manager` to connect and download the `driver.exe`. But since you are saying, you can hit that URL and you can see the response on the page. My guess can be ruled out.

Comment: Yes I tried it on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

I think Service() needs a path to downloaded version of chromedriver.

You can download chromedriver from this [link 1](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) (version 114 or older) or this [link 2](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) (version 115 or newer), and then replace the path inside Service with your actual path to chromedriver (put it somewhere, and copy its path and paste it inside Service())

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Service(path_to_chromedriver_executable)
service = Service('C:\\Users\\akram\\Desktop\\Work\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

url = "URL_TO_SCRAP"
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
```

`Note:` It's better if both chrome and chromedrive are updated.

Comment: Hi Akram. Isn't the point of selenium 4.11.2 and selenium manager that you dont need to specify a path? As in, selenium manager should find the latest version of chromedriver and download it for me. You can see in my answer that when i was using webdriver-manager before Chrome 16 I didn't specify a path and it was working

Comment: Hello Brian, so i didn't use the manager in the scraping process yet, i'm still sticking with the path method . But you're right about the manager, it's more easier to deal with chromedriver installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your project may be running behind network proxy. Try below:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(true); // true or false depends on system proxy settings
//proxy.setHttpproxy("some.host.com:8081/");
proxy.setSslProxy("some.host.com:8081/");
  
//chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)...\\chrome.exe"); //may be needed some times if chrome binary is not in C:\\Program Files...
chromeOptions.setProxy(proxy);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

(Also see my similar response on following link for any further reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12580 )

Comment: what is the library being used here for the first line:
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I had before in VS. I had chromedriver that used to be imported via the package manager. If you used to manage chromedriver via another library, package, or some other custom solution you may need to remove references to that.

It might still be trying to download the wrong version that is no longer available.